# Should I hide API endpoint located in package.json as proxy

Tags: javascript, api, github, axios, endpoint

This is a newbie question. I'm currently working on a twitter clone and added my firebase API endpoint to package.json to use with axios.

```
"proxy": "https://europe-west1-APPNAME-RANDOMNUMBERS.cloudfunctions.net/api"
```

Before pushing my code to Github, should I hide the endpoint? If yes, how can I do that? For other types of sensitive data, I have a git-ignored config file but I'm not sure about how to fix this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they will be able to see this when they use your website.

Answer (score 0):

[Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public)

This should answer your question :)

The Key ist just an Identifier for the App, not the User of the App himself.

Comment: I know, thats what It says in the first Answer. The question just calls it an API Key :)